# integers bumped to characters fread

Tags: r, datatable

I determined that 1 row is causing my integers to be bumped to characters. I am using `fread` to read the data. Using `verbose= T` I found that this row was row number 5 million. How can I tell fread to ignore this row?

Comment: There's no "skip certain row in the middle" option. You could (a) use a command line tool to create a new file without that row, (b) read it in as-is, remove that row, `fwrite` a new file without that row, (c) use the `colClasses` argument to force the column to numeric (you'll get an NA value for that row), (d) Use the `nrow` argument to `fread` the first `n - 1` rows, then the `skip` argument to `fread` all but the first `n` rows and bind the results, (e) just drop the row and convert the column after reading it in...

Comment: Thanks, I used `colClasses`, but it still bumped up to character. I am going to read, remove the problem row, `fwrite`, then `fread` again with `colClasses` specified.

Comment: Determine what the offending character is and use `na.strings = .` to change it to `NA`.  Then it should read fine as integer.

Comment: @RichScriven Great suggestion. The problem is that this row has the exact same names as my column header. Some how the headers get repeated in the middle of the data.

Comment: Then just re-write the file without that row - `write.csv(data[-row, ], ...)` then re-read it